# Nested selects in java

Tags: java, sql

I would like to merge the 2 selects in the code below into a single query with nested selects. How can I achieve that?

**This is my code**

```
  int idst1 = // some Integer value

  String SQLST1 = "select idl from " +
                  "studentlesson " +
                  "WHERE id=" + idst1;

  rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLST1);
  rs.first();
  id1 = rs.getInt(1);

  String curses = "SELECT namel FROM lesson where idl=" + id1;
  rs = stmt1.executeQuery(curses);
  rs.first();

  System.out.println("nxt:" + rs.next());
  String s = rs.getString(7);
  System.out.println(idst1 + ", " + s + ", ");
```

Comment: That's begging for SQL injection.

Comment: You should use a JOIN, instead of a nested select

Comment: Also I don't think the rs.getString(7) will work with the code you provided as there is only 1 column returned by your query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I get it correctly and your tables are as follow:

```
LESSON
------
name1
id1

STUDENTLESSON
-------------
id
id1
```

where `LESSON.id1` is the same as `STUDENTLESSON.id1`

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT name1 FROM LESSON, STUDENTLESSON
WHERE LESSON.id1 = STUDENTLESSON.id1
AND STUDENTLESSON.id = idst1
```

Or written as a proper JOIN:

```
SELECT LESSON.name1
FROM LESSON
INNER JOIN STUDENTLESSON ON LESSON.id1=STUDENTLESSON.id1
WHERE id1 = idst1;
```